# Laravel + Nginx: can we serve app from /something and from a different folder?

Tags: laravel, nginx

On disk

- /var/www/mainapp -> some other legacy .php files without any magic url handling
- /var/www/laravel - > my laravel app

I must serve

- accessing domain.tld -> mainapp
- accessing domain.tld/laravel -> my laravel app

The problem is also that Laravel's app are entirelyt served from  `/var/www/laravel/public/index.php` as you of course know

I am not able to set  nginx to serve /laravel and all subroutes using laravel app

Comment: You just need two `location` blocks, can you show your current configuration please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as simple as this should work:

```
server {
    server_name domain.tld;

    location / {
        root /var/www/mainapp;
        # add php/fpm config
    }

    location /laravel {
        root /var/www/laravel;
        # add php/fpm config
    }
}
```